# java inner class: not public and cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android

I have the following code. Where class SacIndiaHelper is inside class SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter .

```
package com.simha.yatras.database;

public class SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter {

    SacIndiaHelper helper;

    public SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        helper = new SacIndiaHelper(context);
    }

    static class SacIndiaHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private Context context;

        public SacIndiaHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME_sacredindia, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            Message.message(context, "Constructor called");
        }
    }
}
```

I have another package where i am trying to access helper object:

```
package com.simha.yatras;

import com.simha.yatras.database.SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter sacIndiaHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level1placesgridview);

        sacIndiaHelper = new SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sacIndiaHelper.helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

When i trying to compile. it shows error. It says

```
helper is not public in SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter; cannot be accessed from outside package
```

I tried `public static class SacIndiaHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` but still it shows the error. what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On inspection, `SacIndiaHelper` is not public, only static. Try `public static`.

Or alternatively.. make the class `public` and the variables within `SacIndiaHelper` `static`.

Comment: I tried that. I edited my question. still it shows. I have an android example which i could compile without errors. i am using the same code here, it shows this error

Comment: What i tried is a) `public` SacIndiaHelper helper; and b) `public` static class SacIndiaHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper. when i tried both then it stopped showing error.

Comment: This happens because the access modifier is default, by default. The default modifier is accessible only within package.

Answer (score 0):

Call like this

```
package com.simha.yatras;

import com.simha.yatras.database.SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter sacIndiaHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level1placesgridview);
        SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter.SacIndiaHelper helper = 
               new SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter.SacIndiaHelper(context);  
      SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();        
    }
}
```

Because your `class` is `static` and is `inner` class of `SacIndiaDatabaseAdapter` you can call it with like `ClassName.fieldName` as used for `static` fields.